# SCRIPT1006: Expected ')' in IE (no other browser)

Tags: javascript

I have an issue with a plugin that is causing a bug in IE but not in any other browser.

The bug error is:

```
SCRIPT1006: Expected ')'
filename.js (449,35)
```

Looking up this line in the script I can see:

```
   function dependanceLookup(_el, ev = false) {
      if (......etc etc
```

From what I can tell, this is due to ES6 (probably wrong as i'm not fluent in javascript).

Is there a way to change this line so it will work in IE? I haven't posted the whole code as it's from a paid plugin and I don't want anyone copying their code etc.

### #

The fix was :

```
function dependanceLookup(_el, ev) { ev = !!ev;
```

Comment: `ev = false` in the function declaration, there's no defaulting parameters like that in vanilla js

Comment: It is the [default parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters) that is not supported `ev = false)` in ES<6

Comment: Remove `ev = false` default parameter and assign it at the beginning of the function body.

Comment: `function dependanceLookup(_el,  ev) { ev = !!ev; ...`

Comment: Thank you so so much for your help :)